# Clustered table query in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, join, temp-tables

I have a table in my mysql database which has a column `score` and a column `cluster`.

`score` is float and `cluster` may be NULL or integer.

NULL means the row belongs to no cluster, an integer means it does. so of course multiple rows can have the same cluster id.

I want to select all rows that are either NULL or the ones of a cluster that have the highest score.

Is it possible to do in a select or in a select/union constellation or with temperary tables? what is the fastest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, then:

```
SELECT data.* FROM data WHERE data.cluster IS NULL

UNION

SELECT data.*
FROM       (SELECT cluster, MAX(score) AS score FROM data GROUP BY cluster)
        AS max_score
INNER JOIN data  ON data.cluster = max_score.cluster
                AND data.score   = max_score.score
```